# Pagination on Drupal 7 - Smartpaging and Paging modules don't work

Tags: php, css, module, pagination, drupal-7

I want to split my node into multiple pages. I try those two modules without success. I try manually put pagebreak tag without success. With Smartpaging module I get 1,2,3 next pagination, but click on any link gets you to the first page. With pagebreak tag, it cut my node, but pagination is hidden.
Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Could you share some code? Smartpaging does work!

Comment: have you followed the installation steps?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_paging works well, read module's README.txt file carefully and configure this properly with text format admin/config/content/formats and module configuration admin/config/content/smart_paging

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have been setup all from the readme file. All text formats etc. I just get the first page only when I click on any pages (2,3,4...)

Answer (score 0):

Can I just add pagebreak tag manually in content? I would like to do it if it's possible. I try this solution with regular pagebreak tag and it don't work. Is there anything to do before adding pagebreak tag?